# How to safely get byte literal from inside string

Tags: python, string, byte

As a challenge to myself, I wanted to see how I could safely extract a byte literal from inside a regular string. However, I'm not able to safely extract the byte literal out.

Example string:

```py
'b"\\xfeq\\xed\\xad7E\'\\x9a\\xb4_ p\\xdf\\x98\\tC\\xcb\\xe7\\xaa\\x80`\\x93\\x1a\\xf5?\\x03j\\xa4\\x93vT\\xd9"'
```

Goal:

```py
b"\xfeq\xed\xad7E'\x9a\xb4_ p\xdf\x98\tC\xcb\xe7\xaa\x80`\x93\x1a\xf5?\x03j\xa4\x93vT\xd9"
```

Comment: `result = eval('b"\\xfeq\\xed..."')`

Comment: @furas Noted, as well as ```ast.literal_eval()```. I could possibly extend my question towards evaluating it safely, but I'll need to think about it.

Comment: @furas Thought about it. I'll extend the question to see if there are any safe ways to evaluate the string.

Comment: I was trying to encode/decode with [Python Specific Encodings](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings) like `raw_unicode_escape` or `unicode_escape` (after cutting off `b"` and `"` at the end) but without results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending some time going through the documentation, this was the best solution that I could come up with. `ast.literal_eval` Is the best way to evaluate literal expressions from untrusted sources. The `except` clause is left purposefully broad in order to accommodate for any possible errors.

```py
import ast

def extract_binary_literal(input: str):
    try:
        result = ast.literal_eval(input)
        if type(result) == bytes:
            return result
    except Exception:
        pass
    return None
```